# Vector norms and Finding Maximum (value and index)

Tags: julia, blas

I'm running some performance sensitive code and looking to improve speed. I am using `vnormdiff` and `findmax` a lot and wondered whether these are the most efficient functions around? Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you encounter a performance problem, it's good to look at your problem from two angles. First, is my overall algorithm the best it can be? If you're using an `O(N^2)` algorithm but an `O(N)` is available, that could make an enormous difference. It sounds like you're examining neighbors, so some of the more [refined nearest-neighbor algorithms](https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/NearestNeighbors.jl) (which depend on dimensionality) might be of assistance.

Second, no discussion about optimization can really get started without profiling information. There's documentation on Julia's profiler [here](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/profile/), and a graphical tool for inspecting it [here](https://github.com/timholy/ProfileView.jl).

Comment: Tim, thanks for another helpful suggestion. These look like great tools (though I'm still waiting while juno loads the graphic profiler!). I've run the basic profiler and findmax does still seem to be a bottleneck, though it doesn't show vnormdiff at all. To give a bit of context, I'm building an economics model which essentially consists of several contraction mapping algorithms (mostly value function iteration). I use vnormdiff in the 'inf' setting, i.e. the max absolute difference, to check when the contraction mapping has converged.